# Как определить,в каких случаях эффективнее использовать рекурсию,а когда цикл?

Tags: рекурсия, циклы, псевдокод

Вопрос достаточно поверхностного характера.Интересно как в принципе на практике определить, что эффективнее в решении какой-либо задачи рекурсия или цикл?Заранее благодарю за внимание.

Comment: Если работать с иерархическими данными (xml/html, деревья, словари/ассоциативные массивы), то только рекурсия для обхода

Comment: @gil9red *то только рекурсия* С учётом того, что любая рекурсивная реализация может быть преобразована в нерекурсивную - утверждение странноватое... тут скорее надо вести речь о понимаемости и лаконичности, а не о единственности реализации.

Comment: *как в принципе на практике определить, что эффективнее в решении какой-либо задачи рекурсия или цикл?* В подавляющем большинстве случаев накладнЫе расходы на рекурсию выше. Так что при отсутствии явно видимого профита и критичности по ресурсам (скорость, память и т.п.) как правило следует предпочитать циклы.

Comment: @Akina пиши это все в ответ, говоришь правильные и адекватные слова, смысла им в комментариях сидеть нет.

Comment: @BogdanBida Туда же можно добавить про хвостовую рекурсию и её оптимизацию компилятором

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По-своему опыту могу порекомендовать следующее:

**Ответьте себе на вопрос: знаете ли вы уровень вложенности?**

Если да, и уровень вложенности небольшой (например 3 цикла) - то смысла заморачиваться с рекурсией нет.

Если нет, и уровень вложенности может быть динамическим, то ответ очевиден - без рекурсии не обойтись

**В любом случае,**

Начинайте писать код без рекурсии, просто используйте вложенные циклы. Не обязательно с полной вложенностью, достаточно 2-3 вложенных цикла, отшлифуйте их, чтобы они работали корректно. Как только Вы это сделаете, переделать их в рекурсию или продолжить работать во вложенных циклах не вызовет никаких проблем в обоих случаях.

Начиная писать нерекурсивно, Вы с самого начала лучше разберетесь, как работает код, а впоследствие и сама рекурсия.

Answer (score 5):

Любая рекурсия может быть сведена к циклу, по сути это следует из [тезиса Черча-Тьюринга](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%81_%D0%A7%D1%91%D1%80%D1%87%D0%B0_%E2%80%94_%D0%A2%D1%8C%D1%8E%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B0)

> любая функция, которая может быть вычислена физическим устройством, может быть вычислена машиной Тьюринга;

Принципиальное отличие рекурсии от цикла состоит в наличии стека вызова - все локальные переменные и аргументы складываются в стек при каждом вызове рекурсивной функции, а в цикле локальные переменные остаются "на месте".

**В этом сила рекурсии:** при каждом входе в рекурсивную функцию все начинается с чистого листа, а в цикле надо помнить, *что_у_нас_там_произошло_в_предыдущем_проходе?* - иногда это напрягает.

**Слабость рекурсии там же:** за это надо платить - проталкивание локальных переменных и аргументов в стек чего то да стоит и размер стека тоже не бесконечен.

Есть еще одно преимущество рекурсии: **красота и простота**

**Теперь когда и что использовать:**

Набор некоторых правил, которые могут и будут противоречить друг-другу:

1. Если я понимаю, что стека хватит для глубины рекурсии, то выбор в пользу рекурсии
2. Если я понимаю, что скорость важнее - то выбор в пользу цикла
3. Если я хочу красивый код - выбор в пользу рекурсии
4. Если кодом будет пользоваться сторонний человек - выбор в пользу рекурсии (красивый код всегда понятнее)
5. Если мне понятно, что глубину рекурсии я не могу контролировать - то надо идти в сторону цикла

**Как оценить хватит ли стека?**

Допустим, если речь идет о Java, то в стандартной 32-х разрядной JVM размер стека выделяемой на приложение по умолчанию равен 64k, если глубина рекурсии 100, то получается, что на одну рекурсию максимум 650 байт или ~160 локальных переменных и аргументов типа `int` или ~10 типа `double`